# How to create the XSLT for my sample xml?

Tags: xml, xslt

**Sample XML**

```
   <xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
   <w:wordDocument xmlns:w="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml">
    <w:styles>
       <w:style w:type="paragraph" w:styleId="booktitle1">
            <w:name w:val="Book Title1" />
             <w:rPr>
                <w:b/>
             </w:rPr>       
       </w:style>
    </w:styles>
    <w:body>
    <w:p>
      <w:pPr><w:pStyle w:val="booktitle1"/></w:pPr>
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
         <w:rStyle w:val="booktitle1"/>
         </w:rPr>     
        <w:t>Book title</w:t>
      </w:r>
      <w:r wsp:rsidRPr="00C358DC">
          <w:rPr>
          <w:rStyle w:val="booktitle1"/>
          <w:b w:val="off"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t> Author</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
    </w:body>
   </w:wordDocument>
```

In this sample xml, the para text formatting information (i.e. bold) defines within the style property. So, the style will apply the bold formatting for whole para text. But, the word “ Author” run-on property override the bold for the particular text. So, those characters are present without bold with in the para text. So, I need the below mentioned output xml using xslt.

**Output xml:**

```
      <p class=”Book Title1”><b val=”on”>Book title</b><b val=”off”> Author</b></p>
         or
      <p class=”Book Title1”><b>Book title</b> Author</p>
```

Does anyone have any idea how to do this? Any ideas or comments are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Its probably best that you produce some code, and then attempt to resolve your problem yourself. If you have a specific query yoou can then fire away with a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RenderX has a set of stylesheets that process WordML which of course include navigating named styles in WordML through their equivalents stored in alternate places in the file. I would suggest as an answer that you examine how they did them and adapt to your namespaces/etc. if they do not match.

They are at http://www.renderx.com/tools/word2fo.html

And I will also tell you that it is not as simple as you think. Styles in WordML can have linked styles (which in turn can have other linked styles ... and so on) and also you have to know when to apply the default style to some elements (w:p) and not (when a w:p is inside a w:tc or a w:r that is a list). And you must program through the whole chain of linked styles applying them in the right order to achieve matching the style in Word.

While you may think this is not an "answer" to your question, it is.

You asked a question that you think is easy to answer, but I can tell you from experience that RenderX spent many man-years developing those conversions from WordML to interpret the styles.